# Accessing google charts JavaScript module in web app builder custom widget

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder

I am creating a custom widget in ArcGIS Web App Builder for developers where I am trying to access the Google Charts JavaScript API.

I am successfully able to add the Google charts in a simple ArcGIS JavaScript API sample 3.24 by adding the CDN of the google chart in the require function.

Sample: https://output.jsbin.com/wopoxuzeme

The same implemented in the Widget.js file does not work:

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare','jimu/dijit/StatisticsChart',"esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/tasks/query", 'jimu/BaseWidget','https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'],
  function(declare, StatisticsChart, FeatureLayer, Query, BaseWidget) {
    //To create a widget, you need to derive from BaseWidget.
    return declare([BaseWidget], {
      // Custom widget code goes here

      baseClass: 'jimu-widget-gurcustom',
      currentAttrs: {
          chartTr: null,
          config: null,
          layerInfo: null
        },

      //this property is set by the framework when widget is loaded.
      //name: 'CustomWidget',


      //methods to communication with app container:

      // postCreate: function() {
      //   this.inherited(arguments);
      //   console.log('postCreate');
      // },

      // startup: function() {
      //  this.inherited(arguments);
      //  this.mapIdNode.innerHTML = 'map id:' + this.map.id;
      //  console.log('startup');
      // },

      drawChart :function(){
         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('number', 'Distance');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Elevation1');
          data.addRows([[4.49000000,13.87000000],[31.71000000,14.12000000],[35.82000000,15.65000000],[42.03000000,16.94000000],[48.54000000,17.62000000],[49.09000000,15.66000000],[55.02000000,17.65000000],[66.68000000,17.84000000],[77.68000000,18.39000000],[80.19000000,20.10000000],[82.46000000,18.82000000],[94.06000000,17.75000000],[100.34000000,14.70000000],[103.28000000,11.52000000],[114.15000000,7.31000000],[126.61000000,5.72000000],[146.07000000,3.63000000],[172.00000000,0.84000000],[191.64000000,-1.51000000],[215.08000000,-2.71000000],[229.36000000,-2.08000000],[244.06000000,-1.96000000],[288.11000000,-3.25000000],[334.92000000,-4.56000000],[372.98000000,-4.23000000],[413.24000000,-3.52000000],[464.11000000,-3.99000000],[495.79000000,-5.52000000],[520.08000000,-6.62000000],[544.54000000,-7.30000000],[571.22000000,-7.83000000],[622.71000000,-8.35000000],[677.88000000,-9.21000000],[725.14000000,-6.76000000],[776.75000000,-6.57000000],[809.66000000,-7.29000000],[837.73000000,-7.61000000],[855.70000000,-7.83000000],[895.04000000,-8.45000000]]);
          var options = {
            chart: {
              title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
              subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
            },
            width: 900,
            height: 500
          };

          var chart = new google.charts.Line(this.resultsContainer);
          chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
      } ,
      onOpen: function(){
        console.log('onOpen');
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(this.drawChart());




      },



      // onClose: function(){
      //   console.log('onClose');
      // },

      // onMinimize: function(){
      //   console.log('onMinimize');
      // },

      // onMaximize: function(){
      //   console.log('onMaximize');
      // },

      // onSignIn: function(credential){
      //   /* jshint unused:false*/
      //   console.log('onSignIn');
      // },

      // onSignOut: function(){
      //   console.log('onSignOut');
      // }

      // onPositionChange: function(){
      //   console.log('onPositionChange');
      // },

      // resize: function(){
      //   console.log('resize');
      // }

      //methods to communication between widgets:

    });
  });
```

I get Error in console:

```
jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:66 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Container is not defined
    at gvjs_3m (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:66)
    at gvjs__Y.gvjs_7p [as constructor] (jsapi_compiled_default_module.js:232)
    at gvjs__Y.gvjs_gM [as constructor] (jsapi_compiled_ui_module.js:1057)
    at new gvjs__Y (jsapi_compiled_line_module.js:5)
    at drawChart (Widget.js?wab_dv=2.9:51)
```

The Widget.html file is as following:

```
<div>
    <p>Gurminder</p>

      <div class="results-container" data-dojo-attach-point="resultsContainer">
      </div>

</div>
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Have you gone through console and add break points into console? What is Container?

Comment: @Demon I have attached the div container code.

Comment: What is line 66?

Comment: I think container being not defined is more towards Google's Chart API. Maybe this might be useful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730324/container-is-not-defined-google-chart